# Backbone Mocha Testing: "app is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, mocha.js

I'm just trying to run a simple test to make sure the global namespace for my app exists. But I keep getting the "app is not defined" error.

**test/test.js:**

```
var chai = require('chai');
var assert = chai.assert,
expect = chai.expect,
should = chai.should();


describe("Application", function() {
    it("creates a global variable for the name space", function() {
        should.exist(app);
    })
});
```

**js/app.js**

```
if (typeof app === "undefined") app = {};
```

Comment: Are you sure the test runner is started **after** you include your `app.js` file?